# In ruby, symbols that cannot be replaced by strings?

Tags: ruby

As far as I understand, symbols are ways to reduce the memory footprint of strings. So functionally `:firefox` should be equivalent to `"firefox"` in all cases.

However, in some of the selenium bindings, this doesn't seem to apply.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, desired_capabilities: :firefox
```

If I replace `:firefox` with `"firefox"` in that call, I get an error. Is the symbol here actually something more than a slightly more memory efficient string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String`s and `Symbol`s in Ruby are never directly equal. The difference in class is important in more than one way, and

```
:my_label != "my_label"
```

However,

```
:my_label.to_s == "my_label"
```

A Ruby `Symbol` is more efficient than a `String` in a few ways, including:

- A `Symbol` hashes and compares faster, which helps when using as hash keys.
- Multiple uses of the same `Symbol` do not make copies of the internal data, but are just identical pointers to the same object in memory. This makes them memory efficient when you have a lot with the same value.

If a library, such as `Selenium::WebDriver` makes use of a Symbol as a parameter, then you cannot always replace it with an equivalent string. Whether or not you can treat it like that depends on the specific library. It is relatively easy to cast `Symbol`s to `String`s and vice-versa, so a lot of libraries will do that cast for you. It is very common to have library code that does `param = param.to_s` when it needs a `String` param.

Casting from `String` to `Symbol` is less commonly found in library code, because for a long while Ruby would not garbage-collect unreferenced `Symbol` objects - converting arbitrary `String` values to equivalent `Symbol` ones was a way of getting memory leaks (and a vector for an attacker to crash your program).

Answer (score 2):

Symbol *is a* data type.

`Selenium::WebDriver.for` method accepts arguments, and probably expects the hash values to be symbols. I never worked with the class and don't know whether last argument to `for` is a hash or kwargs, but you got the idea: ***datatype matters***.

When you pass "wrong" data type, error is raised.

Comment: Some libraries make an effort to accept both, but yes, it's not automatic at all. Rails spoils people :)

Comment: `4` is not the same as `4.0` is not the same as `"4"` is not the same as `:"4"` is not the same as `[4]` is not the same as ...

Answer (score 0):

To see the difference between a string and a symbol, see the following irb transcript:

```
irb(main):007:0> "firefox"
=> "firefox"
irb(main):008:0> "firefox".to_sym
=> :firefox
irb(main):009:0> "firefox".class
=> String
irb(main):010:0> "firefox".to_sym.class
=> Symbol
```